# "A referral was returned from the server" from ActiveDirectory plugin

Tags: windows, active-directory, wiki, screwturn

I am using (trying to anyway) an ActiveDirectory plugin for ScrewTurn wiki called **UserAuth** (by "ElectricImages").  Whenever a user logs into the Wiki's login page with **correct** network credentials (provides domain\user and password), they get a login error and the ScrewTurn log shows the message *Authentication of ...... failed: A referral was returned from the server*.

If the user gives the **wrong** password, then the log says *Authentication of ...... failed: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password*, so it seems that ActiveDirectory is in fact getting the authentication info.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you authenticating against a server that actually is a domain controller for the domain you're authenticating to?

Comment: Or, to be  a little clearer, are you in a multi-domain environment (forest, trusts, etc.)?

Comment: see comments in squillman's answer

Comment: Seen, but you didn't answer *my* question: do you have a single domain or many trusted domains? Referrals are usually returned when you try to log on to DomainA but you're talking to a domain controller for DomainB.

Comment: The plugin is configured to connect to a certain domain (e.g. ServerFault) and the user who's trying to log in also belongs to that same domain... (e.g. ServerFault\john)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the web.config AD connection string you are using in the plug-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I fixed it... There were 2 problems:

1. I needed to use the fully qualified name, e.g. Source=ServerFault.com (as suggested by squillman)
2. I needed to change the "Anonymous Access" user in IIS to be a network user that has access to Active Directory (previously, it was a local machine user)

Thanks all who helped!

Answer (score 2):

Directory referral messages often indicate that you're either binding to the directory in the wrong place or that you're doing some kind of cross-domain query against a server that might be in the same forest but isn't responsible for the domain in question.  What are you using for the Source configuration tag?  Do you have a domain controller at the site where your server is that is authoritative for that domain?

Comment: what do you mean by "binding in the wrong place"?

Comment: the Source tag is the same as the domain name of the users that are trying to login to the wiki... i.e. Source=ServerFault and the users are logging in to the wiki using: ServerFault\john

Comment: Try using the fully qualified domain name instead.  So instead of Source=ServerFault, use Source=ServerFault.com

Comment: "binding in the wrong place" is actually going to be irrelevant to this issue.  Typically you need to bind to a location in the directory when querying, but this plugin automatically binds.  I don't see any options for configuring this.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this when when the Base DN was set to legit-looking, but non-existant DN.